# How to plot 4D contour lines (XYZ-V) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, 3d, contour, 4d, geometry-surface

I have dataset of XYZ as the coordinates and V as the value at each point (100x4 matrix).

I plot the 3D surface using patch. (by faces & vertices)

How can I plot the contour lines of V (NOT Z) over the 3D surface !?

( The Contour3 function plots 3D contour lines of Z ; But I need contour lines of V. )

Actually I want something like [this](http://www.lausanneheart.ch/images/vector.png) or [this](http://www.lausanneheart.ch/images/pqinterval.png).

Thanks a billion for your help.

---

Well actually I found out that the isosurface command is exactly what I want.

However, this command requires the V data to be a 3D matrix. But my V is a vector. And the data in it is completely non-uniform and irregular. Now here rises a new question :

**How can I convert this non-uniform vector to a 3D matrix, so that it's ready to be used with isosurface command !!?**

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

[`cont3d`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4663-cont3d-m) from MathWorks FileExchange is not exactly what you're looking for, but it may give you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the provided link. It was really useful and gave me some hints and idea what to do. But the problem is that the contour lines in that function (cont3d) were only parallel to the xyz axes. What I want actually is some contour lines ON a 3D surface like human body. Would you please provide some more help !?