# 3d velocity field plotting in matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d

I need to plot a colored velocity field over a sphere in 3d. I'm looking for a function that looks similar to this:

`f(X, Y, Z, V)` Where `X`, `Y`, `Z` represent the 3d coordinates (3 dimensional matrices that are formed using `meshgrid`) and `V` is a 3 dimensional matrix that determines the velocity value for each coordinate. The result should be a 3d colored plot with a changing color according to the value in `V` for every coordinate.

I tried to use `isosurface` but it didn't work well because I need contours, I just need the specific value I have in every coordinate. I used `quiver3` and it works well but I need the plot to be mapped by colors rather than arrows.

I would really appreciate any ideas and solutions as I've been reading lots comments of many similar questions (like this one: [How to plot 4D contour lines (XYZ-V) in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684023/how-to-plot-4d-contour-lines-xyz-v-in-matlab)) and couldn't find any solution.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `scatter3` function. It is very customizable, and may be exactly what you are looking for.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Chris's answer. However, it might be worthwhile to provide a little example on how [`scatter3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) is used:

First:

```
x = rand(1,100);     % x-coordinates
y = rand(1,100);     % y-coordinates
z = rand(1,100);     % z-coordinates
i = rand(1,100)*200;

% specify the indexed color for each point
icolor = ceil((i/max(i))*256);  

figure;
scatter3(x,y,z,i,icolor,'filled');
% if you omit the 'filled' option, you'll just get circles
```

This first example will give you colors **and** size based on the variable `i`. If you want your scatter-points to be in a color dependent on the value of `i` but of uniform size, consider this second approach:

```
x = rand(1,100);     % x-coordinates
y = rand(1,100);     % y-coordinates
z = rand(1,100);     % z-coordinates
i = rand(1,100)*200;

% specify the indexed color for each point
icolor = ceil((i/max(i))*256);  

% after setting the color based on i, reset i to be uniform
i = ones(size(i)).*100;

figure;
scatter3(x,y,z,i,icolor,'filled');
```

Having reset `i` after defining the colors, all scatter-points are of equal size.

Comment: Thank you both very much for your time and effort. This solution works though I use 'trisurf' with 'convhull' command instead after some experimenting.

Comment: With a given data matrix V it looks like this:

phi = -pi/2:a:pi/2;
theta = 0:b:2*pi;
r = r1:c:r2;
[PHI, THETA, R] = meshgrid(phi, theta, r);
[x, y, z] = sph2cart(THETA, PHI, R);

x = x(:); y = y(:); z = z(:);
M = convhull(x, y, z);
trisurf(M, x, y, z, V, 'facecolor', 'interp', 'EdgeColor', 'none');

Comment: @Avshalom.Offner : You can answer your own question if you want to give that comment more room.