# Define scatter3 colours in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to control the colours in `scatter3`?

In my clustering problem I have 2 vectors
`A` = 80x3 containing my data
and `index` containing the indices of the clusters. So for example
the data point `A(i,1) A(i,2) A(i,3)`
belongs to the cluster `index(i)`.

With `scatter3(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),50,index','filled')` I plot all the data-points according to their clusters, but I would like to specify the colour for each group of points.

I tried with the Help, but I didn't manage.

Comment: Have a look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612370/3d-velocity-field-plotting-in-matlab/16649142#16649142), maybe it gets you started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are nearly there. `scatter3` provides several options to define the color scheme (see the doc [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html)). One is indexing with scalars as you do right now. The coloring scheme is automatic in this case. Another option is to use triplets of values representing RGB colors.

For instance, for three colors you can define a custom colormap `cmap`.

```
color_1 = [1 0.2 0.4];
color_2 = [0.34 0.65 0.87];
color_3 = [0.5 0.5 0.5];

cmap = [color_1; color_2; color_3];
```

and then create an `INDEX_color` (Nx3) matrix based on your actual indexing

```
INDEX_color = cmap(INDEX,:);
```

For more groups, you can automatically create `INDEX_color` based on buil-in colormaps. `cmap = colormap(jet(10));` will produce a `10x3` RGB matrix folowwing the `jet` colormap.

The following figure

[image]

is given by this code

```
A = [rand(20,3); rand(20,3)+1; rand(20,3)+2 ];
INDEX = [ones(20,1); ones(20,1)+1; ones(20,1)+2 ];

color_1 = [1 0.2 0.4];
color_2 = [0.34 0.65 0.87];
color_3 = [0.5 0.5 0.5];

cmap = [color_1; color_2; color_3];

INDEX_color = cmap(INDEX,:);

scatter3(A(:,1), A(:,2), A(:,3), 50, INDEX_color, 'filled')
```